# using onfinish of the form (antd) to push to the same path(preventing to push?)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Beginner here, in this my little project using antd's Form 'onFinish' and my Form is in the same page, when i click the button it should update which it does but need to refresh because pushing is not working 'Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack' i have read about ways to solve it where they say 'add 'replace' to the NavLink or Link', but i'm not using link or NavLink i'm using just `history.push(`/Customer `));`.  ways to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `history.replace('/Customer'))`

**Edit:**

Base on your requirements, I've implemented it in such a way that you cannot reload/re-route the page.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4150-forked-wqpdp?file=/index.tsx).

**Note:** I've added a pure HTML Table for the example. You can use `antd` Table, no issues with that.

Just follow the way to do this.

Comment: not working on the same page, when puting some other page it will work

Comment: I think, you better should re-render your Form. Not the entire URL/path.

Comment: at the moment when i click the button it works but in order to see results i need to refresh the page, i want the button to take me to this same url again, or you have better idea could possibly give solution ?

Comment: I've already given. Even I adapted the same method by not reloading the entire page. So, seeing the full source will help.

Comment: there is that manageCustomer where i want it to go

Comment: Going to sleep now. Will see at the morning, InShaAllah. And please upload these snippets to CodeSandbox or StackBlitz.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230570/discussion-between-zunayed-shahriar-and-walee).

Comment: in discussion brother

Comment: Hey @walee, did you checked the latest update?